# How to align the text of a third party Android library

Tags: android, styles, shared-libraries

I'want to make a welcome intro for my android app using the [material-intro](https://github.com/heinrichreimer/material-intro) library from GitHub. I was able to integrate the library in the app and everything works perfectly except for a minor problem; I want to align the text to the left which is centered by default:

[image]

Is there any way I can override this and make the text align to the left?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to go through the source code and modify it yourself if the library doesn't allow native support for text alignment.

Comment: Thanks AlphaQ for your answer